# Replicate Shap.e API How to Save Mesh?

Tags: unity, api

Sorry, I know this isn't really game dev related(but it sorta is because I'm using the Replicate api to generate models for games in Unity lol) But I have a question about API calls. Replicate has an option to "Save_mesh" on it's API. For some reason it's turned off by default and it just saves an animated gif.

https://replicate.com/cjwbw/shap-e/api

Here's the documentation, it says it accepts a bool "save_mesh" but whenever I try passing it in like, "save_mesh" : "true" it's giving me an error on the call. Here's what i tried

```
                string requestData = $@"{{
    ""version"": ""5957069d5c509126a73c7cb68abcddbb985aeefa4d318e7c63ec1352ce6da68c"",
    ""input"": {{
        ""prompt"": ""{inputField.text}"",
""save_mesh"",""true""
    }}
}}";
```

This was working with the Replicate Point-e API call when i formatted it like this,

```
        string requestData = $@"{{
    ""version"": ""1a4da7adf0bc84cd786c1df41c02db3097d899f5c159f5fd5814a11117bdf02b"",
    ""input"": {{
        ""prompt"": ""{input.text}"",
        ""output_format"": ""json_file""
    }}
}}";
```

However, this shap.e API doesn't seem to accept an "output_format" in this format...

Any help would be appreciated, i've been trying to call the API in every way i could think of, setting the bool to "1" and true.ToString() and "True" but nothing seems to work. I'm trying to download a mesh based on a text input. It's weird that the default output is animated_gif lol

Thanks in advance

Edit: I finally got it to work by reformatting it like this,

```
        string requestData = $@"{{
    ""version"": ""1a4da7adf0bc84cd786c1df41c02db3097d899f5c159f5fd5814a11117bdf02b"",
    ""input"": {{""prompt"": ""{ inputField.text}"",
    ""guidance_scale"": 15,
    ""batch_size"": 1,
    ""render_mode"": ""nerf"",
    ""render_size"": 128,
""save_mesh"":true

}}
        }}
        ";
```

However, it's not returning a link to download the model... it's allowing me to submit the api request, but providing no URL to download the obj or anything...

Comment: Have you tried to take a look at the examples and the request made in the dev browser console? For me it looks like true is sent without "" around

Comment: @Zibelas Yes! I was finally able to get it working, it needed to have all parameters added, i was trying to add ""save_mesh"": true before, but it wasn't working unless i added every single parameter lol. Thank you

Comment: Have to taken a look at the full documentation? https://replicate.com/docs/reference/http to me it looks like output will give you the download link in the end for your model or you can ask for it under this section `GET https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions`

Comment: @Zibelas Yeah, i figured it out. The documentation doesn't say anything about how to add the bool, normally it just gives you an animated_gif. However, it's returning a grey model, i wonder if there's some way to get the material as well? Maybe i'm stuck with a grey model, doesn't look like there's any way to request it...

Comment: they are asynchronous so you have to have a system to "poll" to download the model when it is ready.

Comment: @ina Sorry, didn't notice this. The issue was it wasn't giving me a link to download the mesh., it was only giving a URL to an animated gif of the spinning mesh. I was polling the API and waiting until it was ready... I editted my post to include the solution, it wasn't letting me include the "save_mesh" bool unless i included every other property, for whatever reason. Replicate designs this in a weird way, and the documentation was confusing and never mentioned anything about this lol

Comment: are you running it on a a100 instance on replicate or the crappy t4 one?